# Workaround for delete in hive with join conditions

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

So i'm trying to convert a SQL delete query to Hive one. Im using hive .12 version's which doesn't supports delete.

Below is the SQL query:

```
Delete from t1  c where exists(select 1 from t2 a where 
a.emplid=c.employee_id and a.project_status='test')
```

Now i tried tried using NOT IN for the above query but due to some reasons we cannot use NOT IN in our queries.

below is Hive query i have written but i'm not sure as its not giving correct results. i'm pretty new to hive. can anyone help on this.

```
INSERT Overwrite table t1
select * from t1 c left outer join t2 a on (c.employee_id=a.employee_id)
where a.project_status= 'test'
and a.employee_id is null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `project_status='test'` condition to the subquery or into the `on` clause. Also you should select columns only from table `c`.

Example with filter in the subquery:

```
insert overwrite table t1
select c.* 
  from t1 c 
       left join (select employee_id 
                    from t2 
                   where project_status='test'
                 ) a on (c.employee_id=a.employee_id)
where a.employee_id is null;
```

Example with additional condition in the `ON`:

```
insert overwrite table t1
select c.* 
  from t1 c 
       left join t2 a on (c.employee_id=a.employee_id and a.project_status='test')
where a.employee_id is null;
```

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks a lot